# printing pointer value NULL

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers, null

why I can't print a pointer with value NULL?
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int * p = 0;

    printf("%p %p ", p, *p);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is : "Exception thrown: read access violation.
p was nullptr."
I want to understand the error...

Comment: The value of `p` is NULL, the type of `p` is `int *` (`int` pointer) and the pointer itself will print with the `%p` format. But `*p` is trying to access (dereference) address NULL. That's bad since NULL isn't a valid address. Why are you trying to print `*p` with `%p`? The type for `*p` is `int`.

Comment: Because you can't dereference an invalid pointer, it's an _undefined behavior_

Comment: Also it should be `"%p %d "` instead of `"%p %p "` , the second argument is and `int`, not an `int*`.

Answer (score 4):

`p` is `NULL`, which is an *invalid* pointer value - there’s no object at that address.  The expression `*p` in the `printf` call tries to dereference that invalid pointer, and the behavior on doing so is *undefined*.  In this particular case, it causes your code to crash.

Remember that the declaration

```
int * p = 0;
```

creates an object of type “pointer to `int`” (the `*` is only there to indicate type), and initializes the value of that pointer object to `0` (`NULL`).  *By definition*, `p` is not pointing to any object or function, so the expression `*p` is not meaningful.

Not to mention, the type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so you’d use `%d` to print it, not `%p`.

Note - there is a null pointer *constant* and a null pointer *value*.  A zero-valued constant expression in a pointer context (such as `0` or `(void*) 0`) is a null pointer *constant* (the `NULL` macro).  During translation, that null pointer *constant* is converted to a null pointer *value*, which may or may not be `0`.  The null pointer value is simply some well-defined address value that’s guaranteed to compare unequal to the address of any object or function.

Comment: A bit semantic, but I'd argue that `NULL` (or rather a null pointer value) is a *valid* pointer value. But the operations allowed on a null pointer value are limited.

Comment: @IanAbbott: 6.5.3.3, footnote 102: "...Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an
address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the
end of its lifetime."  `NULL` *by definition* doesn't point to anything, so attempting to dereference it results in undefined behavior, hence it's an invalid pointer value.  It's a *well-defined* invalid pointer value, but invalid nonetheless.

Comment: Whether or not a value is valid depends on context. For example, the floating point value 1.1 is valid in many contexts where a floating point value may be used, but not all of them; (for example, it is not valid as the argument of the `acos` function).

Answer (score 0):

Pointers point to a variable. Try with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a = 0;
    int * p = &a;

    printf("%p %p ", p, *p);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `printf` call will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: It should be `"%p %d "` since `*p` is an `int`.Strictly, the second parameter of the `printf` should be `(void *)p`, not `p` (which is an `int *`).